# Добавить свои или переназначить стандартные srcset к responsive img в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, img

В Wordpress в "Настройки медиафайлов - Размеры изображений"
стоят значения: 150px; 400px; 1024px
Также автоматически делается 768px ресайз изображения.
При добавлении изображения через редактор - прописывается:

```
<img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-316" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/18-4-1024x576.png" alt=""  srcset="/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/18-4-1024x576.png 1024w, /wp-content/uploads/2018/05/18-4-400x225.png 400w, /wp-content/uploads/2018/05/18-4-768x432.png 768w">
```

Как изменить для размера 400px и остальных второе значение "400w" на "800w" так как изображение не будет занимать всю ширину экрана.
А также добавить разрешение 150px чтобы получилось так:

```
<img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-316" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/18-4-1024x576.png" srcset="/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/18-4-768x432.png 1140w, /wp-content/uploads/2018/05/18-4-400x225.png 900w, /wp-content/uploads/2018/05/18-4-150x150.png 600w">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для задания своих srcset можно использовать свой фильтр для функции wp_calculate_image_srcset, задав название размера изображения, ширину, единицу измерения (можно поставить px), точку ресайза.

```
function new_custom_sources( $sources, $size_array, $image_src, $image_meta, $attachment_id ){

    $sources = array(); /*Удалить если нужно добавить новые размеры к существующим по умолчанию*/
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $image_new_size = ' thumbnail, 150, w, 560;
                        middle-medium, 400, w, 767;
                        medium, 560, w, 1140';

    $image_new_size = explode(';', $image_new_size);

    foreach ($image_new_size as $value) {
        $data_new_size = explode(',', $value);

        $img_name = trim($data_new_size[0]);
        $img_width = trim($data_new_size[1]);
        $img_desc = trim($data_new_size[2]);
        $img_value = trim($data_new_size[3]);

        $img_url = $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/' . str_replace( basename( $image_meta['file'] ), $image_meta['sizes'][$img_name]['file'], $image_meta['file'] );

        $sources[ trim($img_width) ] = array(
            'url'        => $img_url,
            'descriptor' => trim($img_desc),
            'value'      => trim($img_value)
        );
    }
    return $sources;
}

add_filter('wp_calculate_image_srcset','new_custom_sources',10,5);
```

Если нужны дополнительные копии размеров изображения можно использовать функцию

```
add_image_size('middle-medium', 220, 220, true);
```

где true в конце - это обрезание фотографии, если без обрезки то - false

Comment: Хороший вопрос-ответ, может оказаться полезным другим посетителям. Плюсану.